# acpi keys not working on Asus UX550V

Tags: grub2, acpi

A bunch of ACPI related stuff is not working:

fn Keys f1 through f9 (f10, f11, and f12 are working, which are mute, volume down and up); 
detection when power supply is inserted; and 
backlight of keyboard

I've already changed my `/etc/defatult/grub` file to contain `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=nolapic"` as is recommended in a bunch of different questions. The addition of `acpi=nolapic` has enabled the volume fn keys. Without that, they also don't work.

I've noticed that when running `acpi_listen` I don't even get a response from any of the f keys other than the 3 that are working. (and when removing `acpi=nolapic` those 3 keys also don't output anything anymore).

I don't really understand what ACPI or GRUB is (other than the wiki pages), and what options are available and what they do. Options I've tried so far are the option I have now and the option `acpi_osi=` but that just makes nothing work, much as the default setting.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04